# How to integrate alexa echo dot with salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, integration, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to integrate my alexa echo dot with salesforce, but could not find any decent solution. Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

[Nadim Shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7565124/nadim-shaikh) posted a tutorial on LinkedIn [How-To: Salesforce & Amazon Alexa - Internet of Things](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-to-salesforce-amazon-alexa-internet-things-nadim-shaikh/), which gives a fast track to query some facts from Salesforce via Alexa.

Salesforce itself also posted some videos:

- [Alexa Integration to SalesForce in Minutes with No Code](https://www.salesforce.com/video/7831002/)
- [Voice Enabled Salesforce Apps](https://www.salesforce.com/video/3641671/) - Getting started with Amazon Alexa for Business

And finally a GitHub Project for a [private skill with Salesforce integration](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-salesforce) from AlexaDevs /Amazon, would be a starting point to see how it could be done.